# Ventajas de utilizar const sobre var en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, constantes

En `javascript` puedo declarar una constante de las siguientes dos formas:

```
const CONSTANTE = 'soy una constante';
var CONSTANTE = 'soy una constante';
```

Claro, usar `const` en lugar de `var` hace más entendible el código pero, aparte de eso ¿Existen otras ventajas por las cuales yo debería usar `const`?

Comment: Sólo la primera es una constante, la otra es una variable. No son dos formas de declarar constantes.

Comment: @user1598390 Aunque tienes razón en tu afirmación, eso no es del todo correcto si miras el contexto. Hace varios años ya, la forma de declarar constantes en javascript era usar identificadores en mayúsculas como `MI_CONSTANTE` ya que el lenguaje carecía de las instrucciones necesarias para lograr que un valor fuera realmente una constante. `const` es una adición tardía en las nuevas versiones del lenguaje para resolver esa carencia precisamente, de hecho `const` no protege de las modificaciones a las propiedades de los objetos por lo que estos no son del todo inmutables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al usar `const` se le está diciendo al motor de `JavaScript` que ese dato no va a cambiar, por tanto le estás dando la oportunidad de aplicar optimizaciones que no serían posibles usando `var`. Por ejemplo, cuando el motor compila el código (cosa que [los motores modernos de JavaScript hacen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21237365/4574)), puede sustituir todas las referencias a la constante directamente por el valor de la misma, en vez de tener que insertar instrucciones que acceden a memoria para leer el valor cada vez.

Además de eso, como tú mencionas, el código es más legible: el programador que lo lee sabe que ese valor no va a cambiar durante la ejecución del código. Esta ventaja no es ni mucho menos segundaria, el código debe ser legible ante todo.

Comment: La respuesta estaría completa si añadieras que const tiene scope(ámbito) de bloque a diferencia de var que tiene scope de función lo cual tambien puede ser una ventaja en determinadas situaciones ya que evita caer en los errores de hoisting y permite reutilizar el identificador en los scope externos al contexto actual.

Comment: Tampoco hay que obviar la ventaja que nos da una constante al eliminar errores por un error en una asignación.

Comment: @devconcept ¿qué se ahorra o que se gana reutilizando un identificador del ámbito más general, dentro de un bloque?

Comment: @user1598390 No se trata de reutilizar un identificador en los ámbitos padres sino tambien en los que se encuentran adyacentes por eso usé la palabra externos, perdón si eso puede causar confusión. Ejemplo clásico, tienes dos `if` o un `if` y un `else` que implementan cierta funcionalidad, alguien familiarizado con la teoría en cuestión puede entender tu algoritmo con tan solo leerlo si usas identificadores que tengan un significado obvio para el lector. La alternativa cuando no existe el ámbito de bloque es usar 2 funciones para lograr la legibilidad y en este caso ya no es necesario.

Answer (score 7):

La segunda forma:

```
var CONSTANTE = 'soy una constante';
```

**No crea una constante sino una variable**

La única manera de crear constantes en *JavaScript* (*ES 2015*) es mediante el keyword `const`

La diferencia entre una constante y una variable es que el **la *referencia* no puede ser alterada**, es decir no se puede utilizar el operador `=` para modificar su valor:

Una constante (como su nombre lo indica) no cambia su valor durante la ejecución

**Por ejemplo:**

```
var a  = 1;
a = 2;
console.log(a); //Imprime 2, puesto que es una variable y su valor ha sido modificado
```

**En cambio:**

```
const b = 3;
b = 4; // A diferencia de otros lenguajes esto no es error de sintaxis
console.log(b); // Sin embargo imprime 3 ya que el valor de `b` no puede ser modificado.
```

Es importante notar que esto no convierte el objeto al cual hace referencia la constante sea inmutable, es decir el valor puede ser modificado mas no la referencia

**Por ejemplo:**

```
const c = { nombre : "Juan", edad : 30 };
c.nombre = "Lucho";
console.log(c.nombre); // Imprime Lucho. c.nombre sí puede ser reasignado
```

**Sin embargo:**

```
c = { nombre: "María", edad: "30"};
console.log(c.nombre); // Imprime Lucho. c no puede ser reasignado.
```

Si en cambio deseas también hacer el objeto inmutable puedes utilizar `Object.freeze()`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
const d = Object.freeze({ nombre: "Pedro": edad: 25 });
d.nombre = "Juana"; // No es error de sintaxis pero no hace nada
console.log(d.nombre); // Imprime "Pedro", ya que el objeto d es inmutable
```

`Object.freeze()` no es exclusivo de constantes también puede ser usado en variables:

```
var e = Object.freeze({ nombre: "Rosa": edad: 28 });
e.nombre = "Jaime"; // No es error de sintaxis pero no hace nada
console.log(e.nombre); // Imprime "Rosa", ya que el objeto e es inmutable
```

Sin embargo al no ser una constante toda la variable e puede ser reasignada:

```
e = { nombre: "Tomás", edad: 23 };
console.log(e.nombre); // Imprime "Tomás", el objeto anterior sigue siendo inmutable y no 
                       // ha sido modificado, simplemente ya no es referenciado por la
                       // variable e que ahora apunta al nuevo valor.
```

Otra cosa importante que resaltar es que si bien se puede usar el operardor `=` para "intentar" reasignar una constante (aunque esto no logra nada), intentar volver a declarar una constante es un `SyntaxError`

```
const f = 5;
const f = 6;  // Uncaught TypeError: Identifier 'f' has already been declared(…)
```

Comment: No estoy seguro que tan correcta sea tu respuesta, yo estaba pensando más sobre razones por las que debería utilizar `const` en lugar de `var` si el valor no cambia, tipo el rendimiento de ambas, y no tanto en qué es una variable vs qué es una constante.

Comment: Hola learnercys, en tu pregunta partes por una premisa incorrecta: "que se pueden definir constantes usando `const` o `var`" En mi respuesta menciono este error y luego muestro algunas diferencias entre const y var. Cual uses finalmente depende de lo que trates de hacer. Dicho de otra manera: una no tiene ventajas sobre la otra, cada una es mejor para la situación para la cual se ha diseñado.

Comment: Si, estoy de acuerdo en que la premisa es incorrecta y debe resaltarse. Ahora, centrandonos en que en `javascript` es posible declarar constantes en esas dos formas, siendo la de `var` realmente variable, la pregunta se centra más en las ventajas por las que deberiamos utilizar `const` y no tanto en la diferencia de ambas, porque las diferencias no necesariamente suponen una ventaja. Básicamente para dar una orientación sobre que en caso una variable nunca cambie debería utilizar `const`.

Comment: @learnercys En Javascript no se pueden declarar constantes de esas dos formas, sólo con `const`, no insistas en el error ya que hay lectores que consultan StackOverflow para aprender. La pregunta real sería "¿Hay alguna desventaja de usar `var` en lugar de `conts` para variables cuyo valor no va a cambiar?

Comment: @user1598390 muy bien, debería cambiar el título o el cuerpo de la pregunta? alguna recomendación?

Comment: el const se comporta igual para variables primitivas, en caso de objetos y arrays lo que no cambia es la referencia, mas no los valore; [Agrego una respuesta para complementar lo dicho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/javascript-por-qu%C3%A9-y-son-falso/143907#143907)