# ¿Por qué no funcionan las constantes con objetos en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

Recientemente, con la salida de [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) se introdujo el uso de la palabra reservada `const` que según entiendo es para constantes.

La he probado con algunas variables y todo funciona muy bien, así:

```
'use strict';
const PI = 3.141516;
PI = 3.14;
console.log(PI);
```

Lo cual devuelve el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

Eso es completamente esperado en una constante, pero mi duda surge cuando hago lo mismo con un objeto, así:

```
const empleado = {
  nombre: 'Juan',
  profesion: 'Programador'
};
empleado.nombre = 'Pedro';
console.log(empleado);
```

Lo cual para mi sorpresa me devuelve el objeto con el nodo `nombre` modificado, así:

```
{ nombre: 'Pedro', profesion: 'Programador' }
```

**Pregunta**

¿No debería dar el mismo error al tratar de modificar un objeto que ha sido declarado como constante?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Porque estás confundiendo el concepto de una **referencia constante** con un **objeto inmutable.**

Referencia (en este caso una constante) es simplemente una dirección de memoria la cual apunta a un objeto. En cambio el objeto es el valor al cual hace referencia la constante.

En este ejemplo:

```
'use strict';
const empleado = {
    nombre: 'Juan',
    profesion: 'Programador'
};
empleado.nombre = 'Pedro';
console.log(empleado);
```

El valor de la constante `empleado` (una referencia que apunta a un objeto particular) sigue sin ser modificado es decir sigue apuntando al mismo objeto. Lo que se ha modificado es el valor de `empleado.nombre` no el de `empleado`

En cambio:

```
'use strict';
const empleado = {
    nombre: 'Juan',
    profesion: 'Programador'
};
empleado = {
    nombre: 'Pedro',
    profesion: 'Hacker'
}; // Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
console.log(empleado);
```

Si da un error porque se está tratando de modificar el valor de la constante `empleado`

Si deseas hacer el objeto inmutable debes usar el `Object.freeze()`

Ejemplo:

```
'use strict';
var empleado = Object.freeze({
    nombre: 'Juan',
    profesion: 'Programador'
});
//empleado.nombre = 'Pedro'; // TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'nombre' of #<Object>
empleado = {
    nombre: 'Pedro',
    profesion: 'Hacker'
};
```

Esta vez ya no se permite modificar **el objeto** al cual hace referencia la variable `empleado`, pero si podrás modificar la variable `empleado` puesto que no es constante.

Por su puesto puedes combinar ambas cosas

```
'use strict';
const empleado = Object.freeze({
    nombre: 'Juan',
    profesion: 'Programador'
});
//empleado.nombre = 'Pedro'; // TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'nombre' of #<Object>
//empleado = {
//    nombre: 'Pedro',
//    profesion: 'Hacker'
//}; // Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

De esta forma estarías haciendo que no puedas cambiar la referencia al objeto y tampoco sus propiedades.

Más información sobre constantes en JavaScript en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2237/ventajas-de-utilizar-const-sobre-var-en-javascript/2244#2244) a la pregunta de [Ventajas de utilizar const sobre var en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2237/ventajas-de-utilizar-const-sobre-var-en-javascript)

Comment: Para mi, es ilógico pensar que si modifico un miembro de un objeto no estoy modificando el objeto.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz entonces no has entendido a fondo como se almacenan los valores por referencia en memoria. El valor (a nivel de memoria) de una variable que almacena un objeto por referencia (Array, Function, Object), no es el objeto en sí mismo sino la dirección de memoria (virtual) donde se encuentra el objeto. Es esta dirección de memoria la que es constante no el objeto el cual es apuntado por la referencia.

Answer (score 15):

> La declaración `const` crea una referencia de solo lectura a un
>   valor. Esto no quiere decir que el valor que almacena es inmutable,
>   solo que el identificador de la variable no puede ser reasignado

Esto quiere decir que no puedes sobreescribir el objeto:

```
'use strict';
const empleado = {
  nombre: 'Juan',
  profesion: 'Programador'
};
empleado = {"atributo": "valor"}
```

Porque te marca `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Sin embargo, los atributos del objetos no están protegidos. Así que, como en tu ejemplo, esta sentencia la puedes ejecutar sin problemas:

```
empleado.nombre = 'Pedro';
```

Si quieres tener un objeto totalmente constante puedes usar la siguiente función:

```
 var constantize = (obj) => {
  Object.freeze(obj);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach( (key, value) => {
    if ( typeof obj[key] === 'object' ) {
      constantize( obj[key] );
    }
  });
};
```

En tu ejemplo quedaría de esta forma:

```
'use strict';
 var empleado = {
   nombre: 'Juan',
   profesion: 'Programador'
 };
constantize(empleado);
empleado.nombre = "Pedro"; // Marcará un error, se encuentra protegida.
```

Para más información puedes ver (en inglés):

- [const reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
- [es6-const-not-immutable](https://jack.ofspades.com/es6-const-not-immutable/)

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, fue una difícil decisión aceptar una, sin embargo ambas me fueron muy útiles. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En varias [documentaciones](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp) ya viene explicado que no se puede hacer esto con las variables:

```
const PI = 3.141592653589793;
PI = 3.14;      // ERROR
PI = PI + 10;   // ERROR
```

Pero sí se puede hacer esto con los arrays:

```
// Puedes crear un array como constante
const frutas = ["Pera", "Uva", "Naranja"];

// También puedes modificar uno de sus valores
frutas[0] = "Manzana";

// Y puedes añadirle elementos
frutas.push("Platano");
```

Pero no esto:

```
const fruta = ["Manzana", "Pera", "Naranja"];
cars = ["Platano", "Uva", "Melocoton"];    // ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando marcas algo como constante no estás haciendo que al objeto no se le pueda cambiar de valor, sino que haces que los punteros de la variable no varíen, donde apuntan. Sin embargo, puedes dar otros valores en memoria a estas variables siempre y cuando no varíe el espacio de memoria en el que están almacenados.

Un ejemplo: Si generas un objeto constante llamado Primero con dos variables A1 y B1, y otro llamado Segundo con variables A2 y B2. Si los igualas y haces "Primero = Segundo", realmente estás cambiado los punteros de A1 y B1 a A2 y B2 respectivamente, y es por eso por lo que te salta la excepción. Sin embargo puedes setear de A1 al valor de A2 sin problema, porque estarás cambiando el valor en memoria del puntero de Primero.A1, pero no el puntero en sí mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Para darle una mirada mas hipotetica a esta pregunta antigua. Supongamos que `const` declara constantes inmutables como espera el OP.

¿Que ocurriría con el siguiente código?

```
var empleado = {
  nombre: 'Juan',
  profesion: 'Programador'
};

const e = empleado; //crearia esto un clon inmutable?
                    //o haria que el objeto original fuese inmutable?

empleado.nombre = 'Pedro'; //error?

console.log(empleado); //juan o pedro?
console.log(e); //definitivamente pedro, no?
```

Por supuesto la respuesta correcta es mas simple:

*var*, *let* y *const* declaran **identificadores** de variables o constantes. No crean objetos ni valores primitivos eso ocurre del lado derecho del `=`.

Y, claro está, *const* se refiere a que lo constante es el identificador, no el objeto asociado a este.