# Definir variables estáticas en ES5

Tags: javascript, poo, variables

Quiero consultar a la comunidad lo siguiente, he estado investigando como crear variables estáticas en javascript pero eso no existe de forma nativa en **ES5**, solo en **ES6**:

```
const Varible = "Variable estatica";
```

Ahora bien, realizando pruebas con [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/defineProperty) de la siguiente manera pasandole **window** como el **this** se puede definir una variable a **window** que no se puede modificar o eliminar.

```
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'valorEstaticoPublico', {
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    value: 'Soy inamobible'
  });

  valorEstaticoPublico = 'Me voy a cambiar';
  //Esto da un error ya que no se puede modificar

  console.log('valorEstaticoPublico: ', valorEstaticoPublico);
```

Ahora mi pregunta es la siguiente, esta forma es correcta, es semánticamente correcto, es una buena practica o no se recomienda?

Answer (score 3):

Esa solución tiene un problema, sólo puedes crear [variables globales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_global). Esto por lo general no es recomendado y sólo estarías creando una forma complicada de usar malas prácticas en tus programas.

> El uso de este tipo de variables suele considerarse como una mala práctica, por el riesgo que conlleva esa deslocalización: una variable global puede ser modificada en cualquier parte del programa (a menos que resida en una sección de memoria protegida) y cualquier parte del programa depende de ella. Es por ello que una variable global tiene un potencial ilimitado para crear dependencias, factor éste que aumenta la complejidad.

Recuerda también que [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window) sólo existe en el navegador, [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) también es javascript y equivalente de `window` se llama [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global). Cuando creas una variable dentro de un módulo de node esta variable **es local** al módulo por lo que no funcionará tu solución para ese caso.

Cuando intentas aplicarla para crear una variable en un [ámbito léxico](http://librosweb.es/libro/javascript/capitulo_4/ambito_de_las_variables.html) que no sea el global (en una función) no puedes hacerlo ya que el ámbito léxico y el valor de [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) no tienen relación, este último **sólo** depende de la forma en que se ejecuta la función. Refactorizando un póco tu código se puede escribir

```js
'use strict';

function creaConstante(ambito, nombre, valor) {
  Object.defineProperty(ambito, nombre, {
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    value: valor
  });
}

/* ámbito global */
// equivalente de: 
// const constanteGlobal = 1;
creaConstante(this, 'constanteGlobal', 1);
console.log('global: ' + constanteGlobal);
// funciona pero sólo para las variables globales y en el navegador

function nuevoAmbito() {
  /* ámbito local */
  // equivalente de: 
  // const constanteLocal = 2;
  creaConstante(this, 'constanteLocal', 2);
  console.log('local: ' + constanteLocal);
  // NO FUNCIONA!!!!!
  // si invocas la función directamente te dará un error porque this es undefined 
  // TypeError: ambito is not an object

  // si invocas la funcion como propiedad de un objeto sólo estas creando una propiedad 
  // en ese objeto no un identificador por lo que tendrás un error también
  // ReferenceError: constanteLocal is not defined
}

// invocando a la función directamente
nuevoAmbito();

// invocando a la funcion como propiedad de un objeto
var foo = {
  prop: nuevoAmbito
};

foo.prop();
```

Ten presente que en todos los casos **sólo estás creando una propiedad**, no se crea un identificador como tal que es lo que en realidad quieres lograr.

Para lo que quieres debes usar [babel](http://babeljs.io/) u otro transpiler que transformará tu código de ES6 a ES5 pero este no tiene forma de crear "una constante de verdad" por lo que sólo chequea tu código con el plugin [check-es2015-constants](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants) y lanza un error cuando encuentra una violación. Probarlo es muy fácil.

*foo.js*

```
const test = 1;
test = 2;
```

Luego ejecuta `babel foo.js`

> SyntaxError: foo.js: Line 3: "test" is read-only

El plugin [es2015-block-scoping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping) te transformará los `const` en `var` pero eso será lo más lejos que podrás llegar.

*foo.js*

```
const test = 1;
console.log(test);
```

Ejecutas `babel foo.js` y se transforma en

```
'use strict';
var test = 1;
console.log(test);
```

Concluyendo, si quieres usar constantes reales debes usar un [navegador compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility). Ten en cuenta que [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

> Crea una referencia de sólo lectura a un valor. No significa que el valor que almacena es inmutable, solo que el identificador no puede ser reasignado

Por lo que si creas una constante con un objeto, sus propiedades pueden ser modificadas.

Lee [¿Por qué no funcionan las constantes con objetos en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2808/por-qu%C3%A9-no-funcionan-las-constantes-con-objetos-en-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

En **ES6**

```
'use strict';
const pi = 3.1416;
try {
  pi = 3;
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Pi es una constante, su valor es: ' + pi);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Pi es una constante, su valor es: 3.1416
```

En **ES5**

```
'use strict';
Object.defineProperties(window, {
  pi: {
    value: 3.1416,
    writable: false
  }
});
var pi = 3;
console.log('Pi es una constante, cuyo valor es: ' + pi);
```

**Salida:**

```
Pi es una constante, cuyo valor es: 3.1415
```

Otra convención posible (en JS) es usar todas mayúsculas para determinar qué variables son constantes, evitando sobreescribirlas

```
var PI = 3.1416
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ahora mi pregunta es la siguiente, esta forma es correcta, es semánticamente correcto, es una buena practica o no se recomienda?

No creo que se pueda decir que hay una forma correcta y otras incorrectas, se trata de una limitación del lenguaje y hay diferentes formas de abordarla.

Otra alternativa, no explorada en este post, es usar el module pattern:

No esta tan cómodo como usar una variable, pero te permite contener valores que no pueden ser modificados desde fuera por ningún truco.

```js
var INVARIABLES = (function() {
  var constantes = {
    pi: 3.1415,
    otra: 1234
  };
  
  return {
    get: function (key) { return constantes[key]; }
  }
}());

// modo de uso
alert(INVARIABLES.get("pi"));
```