# JavaScript - ¿Por qué [] == [] y [] === [] son falso?

Tags: javascript

Para lenguajes como Python, o PHP comparar dos array completamente vacíos retorna True como lo es

```
[] == []
```

ó

```
[] === []
```

Por qué para JavaScript no es igual, son elementos diferentes? O qué sucuede??

Comment: No comprendo por qué hay votos de cierre, si no hay uso de la función "compare", como en la pregunta con la que me acusan de duplicado.

Comment: Las preguntas se marcan como duplicado de otra cuando la respuesta de la otra pregunta la responde. En este caso la función compare hace la comparación de igualdad estricta (`===`). Si consideras que tu pregunta no es un duplicado de la otra edita tu pregunta para explicar por qué las respuestas a la otra pregunta no responden a tu pregunta.

Comment: Más detalles en [¿Por qué algunas preguntas son marcadas como duplicadas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Dime tú pues, de qué forma encuentran más rapido la respuesta de la pregunta, para un usuario cotidiano es **nada** normal escribir algo como *"Cómo se deben comparar dos objetos en javascript"*, mientras que *"por qué [] == [] y [] === [] son falso"* es completamente directo a la duda que personas como yo tenemos. La forma de preguntar es muy importante para obtener la respuesta, pero siempre tengo en cuenta que si hablo como la mayoria hablan, me entenderán mejor que intentar ser técnico, y en ocasiones confuso. :)

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Los duplicados no son malos precisamente por lo que mencionas, diferentes personas pueden preguntar los mismo de forma diferente y el propósito de los duplicados es ayudar a encontrar respuestas. Ahora bien, esto no descarta que las respuestas de la otra pregunta pueden mejorarse o bien que se agreguen más respuestas.

Comment: @Rubén exacto, por eso no encuentro logico lo de "cerrar".

Comment: @MáximaAlekz : Si te refieres a la terminología y dinámica del SOes, sería mejor abordarlo en [meta]. Si te refieres a este caso en particular, recuerda que [ask] sugiere incluir una descripción de lo buscado/investigado y por ello si encuentras que las respuestas a la otra pregunta no responden esta es importante que lo menciones en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Quienes votan para cerrar se pueden retractar y aún y cuando se reúnan los votos suficientes antes de que la pregunta se cierre esta queda "detenida" por un tiempo y si llega a cerrarse podría reabrirse, pero esto debe discutirse...

Comment: ... con base en el modelo de SOes.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz : Los títulos de las preguntas no deben incluir etiquetas. Véase [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Esto no es exclusivo JavaScript, el mismo *problema* aparece en otros lenguajes de programación porque se estaría comparando la instancia del objeto/array y no el valor en sí.

Entonces al hacer `[] == []` realmente el primer `[]` no es igual al segundo `[]` porque no son la misma instancia. Cada uno de los `[]` tendrá una identidad diferente. Como sugieres en la pregunta, realmente son elementos diferentes.

Y si `[] == []` es falso, entonces `[] === []` también será falso porque, aunque el tipo fuera el mismo, la identidad es diferente.

---

Referencia (en inglés):

- Pregunta en SO: [Weird behavior of comparison operator JavaScript when using empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19315892/3695983)
- Pregunta en SO: [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/3695983)
- [Artículo de la Wikipedia sobre Identidad de Objetos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming))

Comment: La única respuesta que va al grano y de manera totalmente acertada.

Answer (score 14):

Cuando haces `[]`estas creando un nuevo objeto tipo array es el equivalente a hacer `new Array()` es como la abreviatura, puedes ver que son objetos diferentes con el comando  [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/is)

```js
let miArray = []
let miObjArray = new Array();
console.log(miArray)
console.log(miObjArray)
console.log(typeof(miArray) , typeof(miObjArray))
console.info("son el mismo objeto?" , Object.is(miArray, miObjArray))
```

Por obvias razones si `==` es falso , el realizarlo `===` te va a retornar lo mismo

Para que sean iguales la variable debe estar apuntando al mismo objeto, pero cuando haces un cambio las demás variables tomaran el cambio(objetos mutables)

> [Para ver que tipos de datos en Javascript son mutables o no](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable)

```js
    let miArray = []
    let miOtroArray = miArray;
    miOtroArray.push("se vera en los dos arrays")
    console.info("miArray" , miArray)
    console.info("miOtroArray" , miOtroArray)
   console.info("son el mismo objeto?" , Object.is(miArray, miOtroArray))
```

Answer (score 6):

[] resulta ser false, ejemplo

```js
console.log([] == false);
```

pero son de diferentes tipos, hacemos la prueba con ===

```js
console.log([]===false);
```

Ahora comparamos, pero no podemos comparar directamente `array1==array2`, se debe comparar los elementos, para eso usamos `join();`

```js
console.log([].join()==[].join());
console.log([].join()===[].join());
```

Answer (score 4):

yo te comento lo siguiente para que dentro de JavaScript al momento de comparar dos arreglos aún así estén vacíos retorne true; debes hacer uso de la función typeof() para que de este modo no solo se comparen tal vez en longitud si no en tipo:

```
    console.log(typeof([]) == typeof([]))

//Del modo anterior te va a retornar TRUE
```

También puedes notar que en JS los arreglos son objetos de hecho todo es un objeto por ahí pudiera estar la respuesta

```
console.log(typeof([]))

//object
```

Si quieres obtener un TRUE al comparar dos arrays puedes por ejemplo colocarle valores a cada uno y al momento de hacer la comparación hacerlo por su longitud como en el siguiente caso

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
var arr2 = [1, 2, 6]


console.log(arr2.length === arr1.length) //dará true por que tienen la misma cantidad de elementos
```

Al ejemplo anterior si al momento de comparar le quitas el acceso al método length y haces la comparación dará FALSE

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
var arr2 = [1, 2, 6]


console.log(arr2 === arr1) //dará FALSE por que le quite el acceso al método length
```

Saludos espero darme a entender

Answer (score 4):

Por lo que leí por ahí , es por como se tratan los array, en javascript es de diferente manera ,si bien por ejemplo tu haces esto

```js
var array1 = [];
var array2  = [];

console.log(array1 === array2);
```

te dará como resultado false porque para comparar `array` necesitas tratarlo de diferente manera como recorrerlo o aplicando una propiedad para tratar los array.

entonces si yo ejecuto esto dará true

```js
var array1 = [];
var array2  = [];

console.log(array1.lenght === array2.lenght);
```