# Copiar los valores de un array en una variable

Tags: javascript

¿Como puedo hacer para cambiar un valor SOLAMENTE de `arreglo2` sin que se modifique `arr`?

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var arreglo2 = arr;

arreglo2[1] = "Hola";
console.log(arr);
console.log(arreglo2);
```

(En los dos se modifico la posicion 1).

Comment: ya verificaste que no estés sobrescribiendo también el valor de `a`?

Comment: Por tu código, al modificar b, no debiera cambiar a, ya que `b = a` es una asignación de valor, no una equivalencia bidireccional.

Comment: Perdon, mi problema era con arreglos, para simplificar lo hice con variables primitivas al ejemplo, no sabia que para variables primitivas era al reves, que solo se pasa por valor.

Comment: hola maria en javascript no existe paso por referencia, (como sucedia en vb6) simplemente se le asigna el valor que asuma la variable dentro y fuera de la funcion o metodo [fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es `clonar` el arreglo.

### Solución:

Para clonar el arreglo `arr`, podrías usar [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice)

#### Demo

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var arreglo2 = arr.slice();

arreglo2[1] = "Hola";
console.log(arr);
console.log(arreglo2);
```

Comment: Lo mismo pensé, aunque no sabía con qué método se podría hacer. Buen dato, gracias ;)

Answer (score 4):

Creo que te estás liando innecesariamente, porque lo que dices no es cierto:

```js
let a=1;
let b=a;
a=2;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

El comportamiento que comentas se da con objetos:

```js
let a= { atributo: 0}
let b= a;
b.atributo=1;

console.log(a.atributo);
console.log(b.atributo);
```

Y el motivo es bien sencillo: No es lo mismo modificar el valor de una variable que modificar el valor de un atributo.

En el primer caso tienes un valor primitivo, aunque para el caso que nos ocupa da lo mismo que si fuese un objeto: 1 es un valor y 2 es otro. Cuando a apunta a 1, y b apunta a 1, ambas variables apuntan al mismo sitio. Cuando b pasa a apuntar a 2, a no cambia.

En el segundo caso a apunta a un objeto que tiene un atributo. Entonces b apunta al mismo objeto. Si modifico el objeto (pero no modifico a lo que apuntan las variables), ambas variables siguen apuntando al mismo objeto y, por tanto, ambas ven reflejado el cambio.

### Actualización tras la edición de la pregunta:

Necesitas crear un objeto igual al original (clonar) y guardarlo en otra variable:

```js
let a=[1,2,3];
let b=a.slice();
b.push(4);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) puedes lograrlo:

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var arreglo2 = arr.slice();

arreglo2[1] = "Hola";
console.log(arr);
console.log(arreglo2);
```

Esto lo que hace es que retorna una nueva instancia del array. Si no se le especifica un indice, se copia todo el array.

Answer (score 1):

Otra solucion valida, partiendo de que [los arreglos son objetos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/143907/28035)

Podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var arreglo2 = Object.values(arr);
arreglo2[0] = "lero lero"
console.log(arr,arreglo2)
```