# Editar valores de un objeto JSON dentro de un array Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `array` de este tipo

```
my array = [{N:23/*editar el numero 23*/, k:5},{N:11, k:10},{N:89, k:66}]
```

Y quiero cambiar el numero 23 por otro numero sin afectar el resto del objeto "k:5"

No sé que método o comando puedo usar, ya que si utilizo el método `SPLICE` se actualiza el objeto completo y solo quiero actualizar el primer dato del objeto sin afectar el segundo

Comment: ¿Cómo estás usando el `splice`? Por favor, muéstranos tus intentos, así podemos descartarlos para poder hacer los propios y ayudarte.

Comment: porque usas splice? haz intentado hacer un for y cambiarlo? o apuntar al objeto algo como `my_array[0]["N"] = 32` o algo como `my_array[0].N` de hecho lo que tu habla es un arreglo de objetos no es un simple array

Comment: @JackNavaRow Lo mismo pensé (recorrer el array), pero sin ver lo que ha intentado, no podemos saber nada :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente asignando el valor a esa variable. Deberás ubicarte en esa posición y luego asignarla.

```
var myarray = [{N:23/*editar el numero 23*/, k:5},{N:11, k:10},{N:89, k:66}];

// edito la variable `myarray` dentro de `N`
// y le asigno el valor "13"
myarray[0].N = 13;
```

Aclaración:
`[]` = array
`{}` = objeto

**Para recorrer un objeto en javascript tienes dos maneras:**

1. Dentro de corchetes: `myObjeto["N"]`
2. Con un punto seguido del key: `myObjeto.N`

Comment: el array es un tipo de objeto especial, ten cuidado con eso tu "aclaracion" no es del todo cierta

Comment: te invito a leer [mas sobre arrays](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/143907/28035)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno yo lo haria asi:

```js
var my_array = [
  {N:23, k:5},
  {N:11, k:10},
  {N:89, k:66}
]

function cambiarValor(valorABuscar, valorViejo, valorNuevo) {
  my_array.forEach(function (elemento) { // recorremos el array
  
     //asignamos el valor del elemento dependiendo del valor a buscar, validamos que el valor sea el mismo y se reemplaza con el nuevo. 
    elemento[valorABuscar] = elemento[valorABuscar] == valorViejo ? valorNuevo : elemento[valorABuscar]
  })
}

cambiarValor("N", 23, 30)
console.log(my_array)
```