# Copia de objetos da resultado inesperado

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que recibe 2 argumentos:

1. Una lista de libros (bookList).
2. El libro a borrar de esa lista (book)

Pero después de la función quiero mantener intacta la lista original (bookList) así que la "copio" creando otra variable a una lista nueva (newlibrary)

```js
var bookList = [
  "The Hound of the Baskervilles",
  "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies",
  "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica",
  "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"
];

function remove( library, book ) {
  var newlibrary = library;
  newlibrary.splice( newlibrary.indexOf( book ), 1 );
  return newlibrary;
}

console.log( 'Antes:', bookList );
remove( bookList, 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies' );
console.log( 'Después:', bookList );
```

La función devuelve newlibrary con la lista y el libro correctamente borrado, pero sin embargo si llamo después a la lista original bookList resulta que también me ha borrado ahí el libro:

> Antes: [
>     "The Hound of the Baskervilles",
>     "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies",
>     "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica",
>     "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"
>   ]
>   Después: [
>     "The Hound of the Baskervilles",
>     "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica",
>     "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"
>   ]

Conclusión, ambas listas ahora han sido modificadas, cuando sólo quería modificar la nueva creada y dejar intacta la primera.

¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: Relacionado [JavaScript - ¿Por qué \[\] == \[\] y \[\] === \[\] son falso?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/javascript-por-qu%c3%a9-y-son-falso)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Porque, en JavaScript, los objetos y los *arrays* se usan **mediante referencias**. Eso quiere decir que tú tienes varias referencias **a un mismo objeto**.

```
var newlibrary = library
```

Con eso, tienes **2 referencias**; dos variables que, en realidad, **apuntan al mismo objeto** en memória. Este comportamiento solo se aplica a *objet*os, *array*s y *function*es. **No** se aplica para tipos *primitivos*:

```js
function test( n ) {
  var n2 = n;

  ++n2;
  
  console.log( 'Valor de n2:', n2 );
}

var num = 10;
console.log( 'Original:', num );
test( num );
console.log( 'Después:', num );
```

Para hacer lo que pretendes, tienes que crear una **copia en profundidad** de tu *array*, y **modificar la copia**. Hay varias alternativas, pero mi preferidad, por su simpleza, es usar `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( ) );`:

```js
var bookList = ["The Hound of the Baskervilles", "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"];

function remove (library, book) {
  var newlibrary = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( library ) );
  newlibrary.splice( newlibrary.indexOf(book), 1 );
  return newlibrary
}

var newList = remove(bookList, 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');

console.log( 'Original:' );
console.log( bookList );
console.log( 'Nuevo:' );
console.log( newList );
```

Hay que tener cuidado con este tipo de copias; por ejemplo:

```js
var data = [ 1, 2 ];

data.push( data );
console.log( data );
```

> **Error**: "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Es decir, **no todos los objetos se pueden copiar en profundidad**; podemos encontrarnos, como en el ejemplo, datos recursivos que, sencillamente, son imposibles de duplicar.

**Nota** ( Gracias al usuario [JackNavaRow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow) ). Para obtener resultados simlares, sin preocuparnos por realizar nosotros mismos las copias en profundidad de los `Object` u `Array` implicados, podemos usar librerías externas, como [`immutable-js`](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/). Así podemos tratar todos nuestros objetos como *valores* en lugar de *referencias*.

Comment: otra manera de hacer una copia de array es usar el spread operator: `newLibrary =  [...library]`

Comment: Pero no realiza una *deep copy*, ¿ No ? En el ejemplo es trivial, pero ... ¿ y si fuera un *array* de *array*s ?

Comment: Cierto... entonces _"otra manera de hacer una copia de un array **como este** es usar el spread operator"_ xD

Answer (score 0):

Se debe a que la función splice modifca el array original, como se indica en la documentación.

[Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice)

Si quieres solo obtener una copia del array sin los elementos puedes utilizar slice.

[Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice)

Comment: hola Zerocool. Seguramente el usuario siga confuso porque hizo  `var newlibrary = library`. puedes explicar tambien la creacion de nuevos arrays? y puedes mostrar un ejemplo de codigo usando slice en vez de splice?