# Encontrar index de objeto dentro de un arreglo usando Array.findIndex()

Tags: javascript

Bien antes que nada quiero comentar que tengo una estructura de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
     arrayJson = [{"point":[5,4]},{"point":[2,2]},{"point":[1,6]},
                   {"point": [8,9]} ]
```

El objetivo es encontrar el indice dentro del arreglo que cumpla una condicion y es que "point" sea igual a un valor determinado, he intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
      function encontrarElemento(element) {
          return element.point == [5,4];
        }
       console.log(array1.findIndex(encontrarElemento));
```

No se por qué, pero la salida en la consola me dice que es -1, lo que quiere decir que no esta encontrando el elemento.

Comment: los Arrays son [Objetos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/javascript-por-qu%C3%A9-y-son-falso/143907#143907) por ello no lo puedes comprar directamente, recuerda que [un JSON no es un Objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vayamos por partes:

La comparación entre Arrays no es igual que una comparación entre otros tipos en JavaScript, si comparas `1 === 1` será `true`, pero si comparas `[1] === [1]` el resultado es `false`. Por eso tu `findElemento()` no funciona como se espera.

Una idea que se me ha ocurrido para aproximarlo es reducir primero los valores a booleanos y luego encontrar el índice de true:

```js
const arrayJson = [
  {"point": [5,4]},
  {"point": [2,2]},
  {"point": [1,6]},                 
  {"point": [8,9]} ,
];

const findElementIndexInArray = (element, array) => 
   array.map(({point}) => 
            point.reduce((prev, value, pointIndex) => prev && (value === element[pointIndex]))
).indexOf(true);

const a = findElementIndexInArray([5, 4], arrayJson);
console.log(a)
```

Mira a ver si esto te sirve

Comment: Efectivamente es lo que estaba buscando, excelente solución

Comment: Me alegro mucho de que te sirviera =)
Los array han implementado muchísimos métodos nuevos de un tiempo a esta parte que es muy interesante mirar.

Answer (score 7):

Tenías errores de formato en el **JSON** que has puesto. Una vez solucionado he pensado en esta solución.

```js
arrayJson = [{"point":[5,4]},{"point":[2,2]},{"point":[1,6]},{"point": [8,9]}];

console.log(encontrarElemento(arrayJson, [5, 4]));

function encontrarElemento(elemento, buscar) {
  for (var point in elemento) { 
    if (JSON.stringify(elemento[point]['point']) === JSON.stringify(buscar)) {
      return elemento[point]['point'];
    }
    else {
      return ('Elemento no encontrado');
    }
  }
}
```

Lo primero que hice fue montar un bucle para recorrer los elementos del **JSON**. Al no haber un método directo de comparación de `arrays` (que yo conozca), lo que se me ocurrió es transformarlos a formato **JSON** para así poder compararlos y de esta manera devolver el elemento que necesitas.

**EDIT**

El código de arriba devolvería el elemento que cumpla con el patrón de búsqueda. Si lo que necesitas es que devuelva la posición del `array` en la que se encuentra podrías usar algo como esto:

```js
arrayJson = [{"point":[5,4]},{"point":[2,2]},{"point":[1,6]},{"point": [8,9]}];

var respuesta =  arrayJson.findIndex((item) => JSON.stringify(item.point) === JSON.stringify([1, 6]));
    
console.log(respuesta);
```

Comment: Releyendo tu pregunta, vi que quizás necesitases la posición del elemento en el *array* y no el elemento en sí. Hice una edición a mi respuesta para contemplar ese caso.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(arrayJson.findIndex(item => item.point[0] === 5 && item.point[1] ===4));
```

Convertir a json para comparar es más costoso y se entiende peor que comparar los datos concretos.

Usar map, reduce e indexOf es dificil de leer.

La comparación de objetos, y los arrays son objetos, no se debe hacer con `==` porque ahí estas comparando si se trata del mismo objeto, no si el valor es el mismo. Por ejemplo:

```
var a = [1];
var b = [1];
var c = a;

console.log(a == b); //false
console.log(a == c); // true
```

Comment: ¿Y si el *array* cambia y los *point* comienzan a tener 3 valores en vez de dos? Te tocaría modificar todas las llamadas a esa función para añadirle un tercer *and*. Es cierto que comparar directamente los valores es más óptimo en cuestión de rendimiento, pero también es menos modular. Lo que ganas de un lado lo pierdes por el otro.

Comment: ¿Y si la key "point" cambia de nombre? Es una función para comparar 2 puntos en una aplicación, no una librería