# Como cambiar el valor de un elemento dentro de un arreglo multidimensional en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist

Buen día

Me surgió algo extraño trabajando con arreglos en javascript, probablemente este omitiendo algo investigue al respecto pero no encontré algo que me ayudara

```
var arreglo = [['0'],['1'],['2'],['3']];
```

Luego por realizo un push para copiar el ultimo elemento en cuestion

```
arreglo.push(arreglo[arreglo.length -1]);
```

y la estructura del arreglo quedaria de la siguiente forma

```
arreglo = [['0'],['1'],['2'],['3'],['3']];
```

al querer cambiar el ultimo elemento del arreglo despues del push

```
arreglo[arreglo.length -1][0] = 'finDeArray';
```

no se por que cambia tambien el elemento del indice [3][0] y termina asi

```
arreglo = [['0'],['1'],['2'],['finDeArray'],['finDeArray']];
```

cuando busco que termine asi

```
arreglo = [['0'],['1'],['2'],['3'],['finDeArray']];
```

cualquier tipo de ayuda es agradecida

Saludos

Comment: lo estoy probando en la consola del Browser, y me da ese resultado, la primer pista que se me viene a la mente es que está tomando el número 3 las dos veces y genera ese "bug", sigo investigando

Comment: Lo que te está sucediendo a mi parecer es que estás pusheando el puntero del espacio en memoria que pertenece al elemento arreglo[arreglo.length -1], entonces lo que primero debés hacer es guardar ese elemento en una variable para que se copie y luego hacerle push

Comment: el error es simple [] es un objeto ,y estas apuntando al mismo en el ultimo elemento, al cambiar el ultimo valor  estas cambiandolo en el mismo , los arreglos son objetos especiales en casi todos los lenguajes de programacion

Comment: Posible duplicado de [JavaScript - ¿Por qué \[\] == \[\] y \[\] === \[\] son falso?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/javascript-por-qu%c3%a9-y-son-falso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero deberías guardar el valor del elemento en una variable antes de hacer push

```
var arreglo = [['0'],['1'],['2'],['3']];

var elemento = [arreglo[arreglo.length -1]]

arreglo.push(elemento)

arreglo[arreglo.length -1][0] = 'finDeArray';

0: ["0"]
1: ["1"]
2: ["2"]
3: ["3"]
4: ["finDeArray"]
```

Comment: También me funciona esta respuesta, de hecho me es bastante util ya que el arreglo puede tener un indeterminado elementos por indice, por lo que esto me asegura obtener el numero de elementos del ultimo indice del arreglo dinamicamente, y editar el primer elemento del subindice, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tu error pasa porque estas incluyendo el índice `[0]` en la asignación de **finDeArray**. El código debería ser

```
arreglo[arreglo.length -1] = ['finDeArray']
```

Comment: Cierto me funciono muchas gracias por la respuesta, tienes razón no debía haber incluido el indice [0] en la modificación del ultimo elemento del array :)

Comment: @MikeMtz recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te sirvio