# no se modifica cada elemento individual en mi array

Tags: html, array, vue.js, vuejs

tengo un array de bidimensional para unos asientos, al checar en consola me aparece que su longitud es de 2 y dentro tiene 10 arrays con un atributo imagen(la foto del asiento).Los imprimí en pantalla usando Vue.js con un v-for. Sí se me imprimen mis asientos pero al querer modificar el asiento 1 de la columna 1 también se modifica el asiento 1 de la columna 2 y no sé cuál es la razón. Éste es mi código. Tengo la sospecha que mi error está en la impresión de mis asientos

```js
        const vue = new Vue({
    
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                fila: [],
                columna: [],
                des: 'ocupado.png',
                oc: 'desocupado.png',
                total: 0,
                datos: null,
                i: 0,
            },
            methods: {
                cambiar: function(x, y) {
    
                    if (this.fila[x][y].imagen == "desocupado.png") {
                        this.fila[x][y].imagen = "ocupado.png";
    
                        this.total = this.total + 30;
                        console.log(this.fila[x][y]);
    
                    } else {
                        if (this.fila[x][y].imagen == "ocupado.png") {
                            this.fila[x][y].imagen = "desocupado.png";
    
                            this.total = this.total - 30;
    
                        }
                    }
    
    
                },
    
                tamañoColumna: function() {
                    var i = 0;
                    var j = 0;
                    while (j < 2) {
                        while (i < 10) {
                            this.datos = {
                                imagen: 'desocupado.png'
                            }
                            this.columna.push(this.datos);
                            i++;
                        }
                        this.fila.push(this.columna);
                        j++;
                    }
    
                }
            },
            mounted() {
    
                this.tamañoColumna();
            },
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
            <div v-for="(chairs,nfila) in fila">
                {{nfila}} fila
                <div v-for="(chair,ncolumna) in columna">
                    {{ncolumna}} columna
                    <a href="#" @click.prevent="cambiar(nfila,ncolumna)"><img :src='fila[nfila][ncolumna].imagen' height="50px" width="50px"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2>total:{{total}}</h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: Voy a votar para cerrar esta porque hiciste una muy parecida hoy pero mejor explicada y tuvo más respuestas. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326356/por-qu%c3%a9-se-modifica-todo-mi-array

Answer (score 0):

el fallo está en la función de inicialización tamañoColumna() ya que la variable i la tienes que inicializar a 0 en cada pasada del bucle principal. Eso y también crear un nuevo array columna en cada pasada. Viendo el código modificado y comparándolo con el tuyo creo que verás a lo que me refiero:

```
    tamañoColumna: function() {
      let j = 0;
      while (j < 2) {
        let i = 0;
        this.columna = [];
        while (i < 10) {
          this.datos = {
            imagen: 'desocupado.png'
          }
          this.columna.push(this.datos);
          i++;
        }
        this.fila.push(this.columna);
        j++;
      }
    }
```

Saludos